# R Help: Reading Unique Text String in R and Replacing it with Zero

Tags: r

I have a text file like the following. I would like to remove the string with `I` and replace it with `000000`. How could I do it?

```
000003I000000 000000 000010 000005I000000 000000
000000 000000 000000 000000 000000 000000 000000
000000 000000 000000 000000 000000 000000 000000
```

Comment: Look at documentation for `gsub`

Comment: Show what you deem to be the correct answer. Since this is not R code, we cannot tell what you consider to be "a string".